# Galaxy Prime iLocker virus

Tags: lock-screens, antivirus

A friend's Galaxy Grand Prime was infected by a virus, I tried factory reset, and surprisingly the virus appeared on screen once factory reset completed and the phone restarted:
[image: screen shot]

I tried hard reset, but both secret code and key combination (HOME+VOLUME UP+POWER) not working.
The virus is really annoying, installing some apps like Hola and Biadu, and whenever I try to remove them, they are just there after restarting the phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some malwares can use exploits to get root access and copy themselves to `/system` partition that is not wiped by the factory reset. You can find a good writing about them [here](https://www.fireeye.com/blog/threat-research/2015/09/guaranteed_clicksm.html). The only way that is %100 guaranteed to remove it completely is flashing Stock ROM. Find the Stock ROM for your device [here](http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/) and follow the instructions from [here](http://forums.androidcentral.com/ambassador-guides-tips-how-s/499009-guide-samsung-how-flash-stock-rom-via-odin-new-interface.html).